# How do I access declared functions the done() scope of a jQuery plugin that makes JSON requests like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous

I'm trying to keep a jquery plugin I'm working on configurable, and someone what maintainable, by keeping the various functions I use short and relatively easy to test.

To this I'm using some jQuery plugin code, based around the [jQuery boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/), [Addy Osmani's Lightweight Start](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/), to have a plugin where I can pass in overrides, and compose existing functions from a series of small ones.

However, I'm having some trouble working out how to access functions I've declared from within a deferred `done()` callback, without declaring all the function code inside the `done()` function call again.

Is there a recommended pattern for making these functions available when using a prototype based approach like outlined in the boilerplate?

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

  var pluginName = 'myModule';

  function myModule(element, options) {
    this.element = element;

    //  allow override of defaults
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;

    // calling the init() function defined below
    this.init();
  }

  myModule.prototype = {

    init: function() {
      // add listeners for clicks on the element, and trigger some 
      // behaviour defined in fetchScore()
      $(this.element).click(function() {
        that.fetchScore();
        return false;
      });

    },
    handySuccessFunction: function() {
      // some handy DOM manipulation stuff,
      // kept out the main fetchScore function,
      // ideally to make it more testable and readable
    },
    handyFailingFunction: function() {
      // same again for failing case
    },

    fetchScore: function(authToken) {

      $.getJSON(this.options.endpoint, {
        apiKey: this.options.apiKey,
        otherParam: this.options.otherParam,
        token: authToken
      })
        .done(function(json) {
        // I want to call the handySuccessFunction() here,
        // but I have no access to myModule
      })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        // Likewise I want to call the handyFailingFunction() here
      });
    }
  }

  // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
  // preventing against multiple instantiations. 
  // We store a reference to the 
  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
          new pluginName(this, options));
      }
    });
  }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Here's my expected usage:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // console.log('clicking the popup');

  $('#elementToAttachTo').myModule();

  // clicking on this to trigger the fetchScore
  // behaviour in myModule
  $('#elementToAttachTo').click();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "bind" to callback function in "done", set it context ("this") to myModule instance, where this function was declarated.

There are several ways.

1. You can use navtive Function.prototype.bind() method, which works in modern browsers
2. You can use jQuery $.proxy function.

So

```
 myModule.prototype.fetchScore = function(authToken) {
    $.getJSON(this.options.endpoint, {
      apiKey: this.options.apiKey,
      otherParam: this.options.otherParam,
      token: authToken
    })
    .done(function(json) {
        this.handySuccessFunction();
    }.bind(this))
    .fail($.proxy(function(json) {
        this.handyFailingFunction();
    }, this))
    ;        
 };
```

Comment: Since support for `Function.prototype.bind` is still a little sketchy, it might be easier to just assign `this` to a regular lexical-scope var at the beginning of `fetchScore`.  http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind

Comment: I strongly guess it is an antipattern. It breaks structure of code and can cause memory leaks. I prefer always to bind "this".

Comment: Binding `this` to a lexical var has exactly the same implications for garbage collection as binding a function to the same value. But everyone (including me) has their religious convictions on this kind of thing, and I don't want to draw out this particular argument, so ok.